# C++ constructor initialisation list

Tags: c++

I have a class, Auteur, with the following constructor, copy constructor and destructor:

```
class Auteur
{
    public:
        Auteur(string nom, bool prime=false) : nom_(nom), prime_(prime)  {}

        Auteur(const Auteur& a)=delete;

        ~Auteur()   {}

    private:
        string nom_;
        bool prime_;
};
```

Now I want to create a new class that uses the class *Autheur* along with two other parameters. I tried like this, but it didn’t work. How can I write the correct constructor for *Oeuvre*?

```
class Oeuvre
{
    public:
        Oeuvre(string titre, Auteur const& auteur_, string langue)
         : titre_(titre), auteur(nom, prime), langue_(langue)

        Oeuvre(Oeuvre const& o) = delete;
         : titre_(o.titre_), auteur_(o.auteur_), langue_(o.langue_)        {}

        ~Oeuvre()   {}

        public:
            Auteur auteur_;
            Auteur auteur;
            string langue_;
            string titre_;
    };
```

I don`t want to change the copy constructor. But I still have a problem when I try to create a new *Oeuvre* in main:

```
int main()
{
  Auteur a1("Victor Hugo"),
         a3("Raymond Queneau", true);

  Oeuvre o1("Les Misérables" , a1, "français"),
         o2("L'Homme qui rit", a1, "français");

  return 0;
}
```

Since the program needs four parameters for the constructor (*Oeuvre*) and in the main() I create some objects with only three parameters I get an error. (I don’t want to change the main().)

What can I do about this?

Comment: What on earth is `**auteur(nom, prime)**` all about?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? One problem I see is, copying of objects of type `Auteur` is prohibited but you are passing references to objects of `Auteur` as parameters to the constructor of `Oeuvre`. Try removing the `=delete` in `Auteur` copy constructor and see if you still have compiler errors.

Comment: Can you explain why you are disabling the assignment operator in your Autere class? Nothing in your Autere class suggests that the assignment operator is dangerous, unwanted, expensive, resource hogging, or anything.  Your class consists of just two simple member variables.

Comment: **auteur(nom, prime)** is supposed to be auteur(nom, prime)

Comment: @user3443063 - It looks like you're looking for a problem to a solution.  I would suggest not disabling any operators until you have justification to do so.  In both your Autere and Oeuvre classes, you don't need to disable these operators for these simple classes and types.

Comment: The problem I have to solve doesn`t allow the class Auteur to be copied. Thats the reason why I deleted the copy constructor of Autheur.   I now get different errors that all tell me that there is a parameter missing.

Comment: Advice #0, use English for all identifiers and comments in all your programs, so that people across the globe can read them easily.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `Auteur` members (`auteur` and `autheur_`) ? **Obviously, if you cannot copy `Auteur` object** then you have to do some other changes but as we don't have the specification of your homework, it is hard to guess. You either need to pass separate arguments or keep a reference to original object or have some way to get information from the `Auteur` to make a manual copy (which would be nonsense).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Use const& for string parameters.  They're going to get copied
   anyways into the members so no need for the extra copy just to pass
   them in to the functions.
2. Deleting the copy constructor for Auteur is fine; it's simply
   ensuring that the object cannot be passed by value and must be
   passed by reverence whenever it's used.
3. It doesn't make sense to delete the copy constructor for Oeuvre and
   also give it an implementation.  Either have one or don't but you
   can't have both.
4. If you don't need a separate copy of Auteur but only want to
   reference an existing object, keep it as a constant reference member
   instead.
5. No need to define an empty destructor.  You will automatically get
   the default.

Given those things:

```
#include <string>

class Auteur
{   
public:   
  Auteur(std::string const& nom,  bool prime=false)          
  : nom_(nom), prime_(prime)  
  {}

  Auteur(Auteur const&) = delete;         

private:
  std::string nom_;
  bool prime_;
};
```

.

```
class Oeuvre
{   
public:   
  Oeuvre(std::string const& titre, std::string const& langue, Auteur& auteur)
  : titre_(titre), langue_(langue), auteur_(auteur)
  { }

  Oeuvre(Oeuvre const&) delete;

public:
  const Auteur &auteur_;
  std::string langue_;
  std::string titre_;
};
```

.

```
int main()
{
  Auteur a1("Victor Hugo"),
         a3("Raymond Queneau", true);

  Oeuvre o1("Les Misérables"  , "français", a1),
         o2("L'Homme qui rit" , "français", a1);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you `delete`d the copy constructor of class `Auteur`, which means that a construction like

```
Auteur a1("Victor Hugo");
Auteur a2(a1);
```

is now illegal, since `a2` will be copy-constructed from `a1`.

The initializer list of a class' constructor isn't different from this. You're constructing `o1` with several parameters, one of which happens to be `a1`. Now well, within `Oeuvre`'s constructor, you're initializing (i.e. constructing) member `auteur` from it, which is using the copy constructor -- which you `delete`d!

There are two ways of working around this:

1 - Don't `delete` `Auteur`'s copy constructor. Since this class doesn't appear to manage any resource, that's fine.

2 - Give `Oeuvre`'s constructor the parameters it needs to properly initialize an `Auteur`. I wouldn't go with this one, because it certainly doesn't concern this class to do such thing.